# How can I validate if the content of a string is accepted using interfaces of TS?

Tags: typescript, interface

I want to check if the content of a string is accepted.

```
export interface paramsHttpRequest {
    type: string, // This type should be "POST" or "GET"
    url: string,
    headers?: [object],
    body?: JSON
}
```

How make sure that type came as *POST* ou *GET*?

Comment: Presumably you want a union of string literal types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPxpW), so `"POST" | "GET"` instead of `string`.  Does that meet your needs?  If not, please [edit] the code example to demonstrate the unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Yes @jcalz, that's exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), which are represented in the type system as quoted string literals.  A string literal type only accepts a single, specific string value.  For example, the type `"POST"` only accepts the value `"POST"`:

```
let a: "POST";
a = "POST"; // okay
a = "GET"; // error! Type '"GET"' is not assignable to type '"POST"'
```

TypeScript also has [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), which are represented by joining other types with a vertical bar (`|`); so if `A` and `B` are types, then `A | B` is a union type with `A` and `B` as the *members* of the union.   A union type accepts a value  if and only if that value is accepted by at least one of its member:

```
let b: string | number;
b = "hello"; // okay
b = 123; // okay
b = false; // error! Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number'
```

If you want the `type` property of `ParamsHttpRequest` to accept only `"POST"` or `"GET"` and nothing else, then you should declare it to be of type `"POST" | "GET"`:

```
interface ParamsHttpRequest {
    type: "POST" | "GET"
    url: string,
    headers?: [object],
    body?: JSON
}

const x: ParamsHttpRequest = {
    type: "GET",
    url: "/"
} // okay

const y: ParamsHttpRequest = {
    type: "OOPS", // error!
    // Type '"OOPS"' is not assignable to type '"POST" | "GET"'
    url: "/"
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBBEAFA8gZQCrwNwFgBQUEAvAihthAPSUQD2A1lAJ76EnwDiAopllTSABOg2oICEEdEwAOICAHJOPePIgBLAM4QAdrUhQNGtQHNtUAEagIYWtZlzFZTPPz5Qkc3A1hBa7cYgAHx0AVwBbcyFcPHNiBAALEGBgWgpqOkYWGLiARgAmAGY+dIZmfFiSADMoYA0QYoFhUQkpWQVzWlpQKG1VTR09aEMTM0s5Gzs2+W9ffyDQiKEXPFc8EAAPaVFIPzAhaoBjOUQoQSgwjQAJMDBpACUQAEcQkG8IAG98CG-JkDgkNCYeZKTBfH4hQTALw+PzGAA0YO+iSgABMhBoAPxwADatHMACsQAcwABdBF4H4QDoophYiAAKVQyAAcvgAL6rA60bRvdZwE5nC7XW4PZ6vSAkT4Un5gez-biYcmUiFQhCUeDs-gZMp4Lk8yBMfmnc5XG73J4vN6SxG-f7IZCIVDwOFaoQicQ29KtBzwe2OlTqLS6fTDUwWKwTWVTAHkYEKlQ2lX-dXs-BAA)